# How does javascript detect an anonymous comma?

Tags: javascript

I'd wrote a small example to split an array (implicit conversion) and alerted each item via a loop.

My test code:

```
var x = '1, 2';
x.split(',').forEach(function (i) {
   alert(i)
})
```

I didn't understand since I changed it to:

```
var x = '1';
x.split(',').forEach(function (i) {
   alert(i) //output: 1
})
```

Where is the comma (',') in the second? I think it shouldn't work because no comma was found in the string.

Comment: As far as I know, all commas reject the notion of having names entirely. They're *all* anonymous.

Comment: Anyway `.split()` always returns an array with at least one element. That's the way the API works.

Comment: `'1'.split(",")` yields a result of `['1']` - hence why your `forEach` runs once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation for [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

> If separator is not found or is omitted, the array contains one
>   element consisting of the entire string.

When you do

```
var x = '1';
x.split(',')
```

no comma is found so an array with one item containing `'1'` is returned

Comment: @HappyCoding, no problem. Glad the answer helped :-)